Correct regression to use for longitudinal pest survey between two groups across multiple sites
THE DATA: We have 3 sites with a total of 36 plants growing in them: each site contains 12 plants (6 belonging to spp1 and 6 belonging to spp2). The size and geolocation of each plant is known. Each plant was checked for abundance of a pest (raw counts) every 10-14 days for 6 months. As a result, each plant has approximately 18 pest count data points.

Note:  2 sites are ~500m apart, while the 3rd is 8 km away from the other 2. Within each plot, plant distributions overall are somewhat homogenous, but there is definitely some obvious clumping of sample plants within any given plot (say, 2 sample plants being <5m apart while a 3rd may be 50m apart from them).

HYPOTHESIS: We will trap more pests on spp2 than on spp1
MODEL SELECTION: So we clearly need some sort of regression here (PestAbundance ~ PlantType), but it should potentially incorporate size and geolocation as well.

QUESTION(S):

What's the best way to incorporate the "repeated measures" structure of this study? Does this simply call for a mixed effects model? If so, do we have enough data to build this model and to expect reliable coefficient estimates? (especially if trying to incorporate impacts of size and geolocation).

What's an appropriate way to design this model? (i.e., how do we incorporate the "structure" of our data having repeated measures of 36 individual plants?


What's the best way to incorporate geolocation (lat and long) into this model? Should we incorporate lat/long as two separate variables, or is there some elegant way to combine them? (especially without diminishing our ability to run a reliable test with our current size of data)




BONUS: any guidance in R is always helpful :)  [nlme or lme4 in this case?]

Are the plans meaningfully far apart within each site? Or can each site be considered homogenous except for the plant type variation?

Not completely thought out, but here are some impressions: Sounds like an Poisson process whose rate parameter varies according to a latent stochastic process. Perhaps something like a log-Gaussian process with some choice of kernel. See Statistical Rethinking 2023 - 16 - Gaussian Processes for some intuition about continuous partial pooling.
Maybe RStan will have the functionality to develop such a model.

@dimitriy: 2 sites are ~500m apart, while the 3rd is many km away from the other 2. To answer your question, plants in each plot are somewhat homogenous, but there is definitely some clumping of sample plants going on even within any given plot. I think the effect will be minor, but I would not at all be surprised if some spatial autocorrelation is at play here. I'd like to at least test for it through some model comparison if possible.

@Galen Huh. That feels like way out in left field compared to the mixed model approach I was thinking. I'm very unfamiliar [unaware] of your approach(es), so I've got some reading to do. I much appreciate the insight! Thanks!

In your place I would start not with "the best model" but with a model that captures some but not necessarily all aspects of interest. And then expand the model step by step. FWIW I suspect that it might be challenging to incorporate latitude and longitude in a very sophisticated way since the geolocation sampling is quite sparse. Another general option is GAMs eg with the {mgcv} package. There are lots of GAM-related questions on CV.
